# VS2010 designer not working when the ResourceDictionary is in a subfolder

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a project which contains the entry point of my application and a ResourceDictionary. In a first time, these files were located at the root of the project. At this time, I could see all the components (button for exemple) modified by the style in the designer of xaml files in other projects.

Now, I have subfolders like this : src/launcher which contains my entry point and src/styles which contains my ResourceDictionary. But now, the components are not styled in the designer of VS2010. The program compiles and works well, but the designer doesn't work. I get the "Cannot find the resource ..." error constantly.
The code of my main xaml file is :

```
<Application x:Class="MANAGER.Program"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Style.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Why the designer doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look this way in order to use subdirectories out of your application root directory:

```
<Application x:Class="MANAGER.Program"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,../Styles/Style.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the format of the "Source" attribute.
The format needs to be a Pack URI like "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/SiteOfOriginFile.xaml"

Have a look at these documentations in MSDN:

- [ResourceDictionary.Source Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.source.aspx)
- [Packet URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa970069.aspx)

Comment: I've tried "Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/src/style/style.xaml" but the program doesn't run. There is an exception at the beginning of the line. I've tried "Source="pack://application:,,,/src/style/style.xaml" too. The program is running but I have the same problem as in the question

Comment: What WPF interpretes as the siteOfOrigin directory depends on what kind of application you have (stand alone, cloick once, ...). Get a debug output of the interpreted siteOfOrigin path and compare it to your real folder structrue in the file system, and see if it really looks for the file where you expect it. Also, please check if you need to add an additional UriKind (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.urikind.aspx) parameter to distinct between absolute and relative paths. Does it work with a full absolute path?